# R conditional selection from dataframe

Tags: r

So I have a large data-frame with usage for a mass subscribers, containing columns sub_type, minutes,  SMS. Minutes and SMS are actual usage while sub_type is identifier for subscription,  i.e. say we have four subscriptions, 1, 2, 3 and 4. How would i create a plot(minutes,sms) for each subscription.

```
> allsubs
> plot(allsubs$minutes, allsubs$sms)
```

this will plot all, regardless of subscription type. So i have solved this by making 4 diffrent dataframes, making 4 queries to database via R. There must be a easier way, that i havent stumbled upon yet. Please let me know if anyone has a tip/link on how to solve this.

Kind regards,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the formula interface to `plot`. It's pretty much the same as you'd use for a modelling function, assuming you've used one of them (like `lm`, `glm`, `rpart` etc).

```
plot(sms ~ minutes, data=allsubs, subset=sub_type == 1)
plot(sms ~ minutes, data=allsubs, subset=sub_type == 2)
plot(sms ~ minutes, data=allsubs, subset=sub_type == 3)
plot(sms ~ minutes, data=allsubs, subset=sub_type == 4)
```

Alternatively, you can use `subset` and `with`:

```
with(subset(allsubs, sub_type == 1), plot(minutes, sms))
with(subset(allsubs, sub_type == 2), plot(minutes, sms))
with(subset(allsubs, sub_type == 3), plot(minutes, sms))
with(subset(allsubs, sub_type == 4), plot(minutes, sms))
```

Comment: Do i need any package to make use of this functionality?  

TRPL_ID MINS SMS
1 15      2    0        
2 13     267  54      
3 28      765  181     
4 13      106  49       
5 13      98   61    
> plot(MINS ~ SMS, data=allsubs, TRPL_ID == 15)
Error in plot.xy(xy, type, ...) : invalid plot type

Comment: I forgot to add the `subset=` bit, which was the crucial part of the function call. Oops! Now fixed up.